# Tengo que borrar las colecciones cada vez que modifico el codigo en moongose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

no sé si es algo que estoy haciendo mal, pero cada vez que modifico mi código y lo guardo, para realizar una petición me "Schema hasn't been registered for model".  Al borrar la colección o colecciones si está usando populate, puedo volver a realizar peticiones. La verdad es molesto tener que hacerlo todo el tiempo, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola Mauro, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Recuerda realizar el [tour]. Ya nos contaste el problema, pero no podemos ayudarte si no sabemos exactamente como tienes definido el modelo, como inicializas los modelos, como tienes configurado todas las partes relacionadas con el problema... Debes compartir tu código para nosotros poder hacernos una idea del contexto del problema y poder brindarte una posible solucion. Saludos